# will salesforce /deleted give only hard delete objects?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I was searching through salesforce and I know queryAll and getDeleted can return `deleted` objects. But what I don't understand is Will `/deleted` return only hard deleted objects of last 15 days or it will also return soft deleted objects also?

Answer (score 0):

If a record is hard deleted it is no longer on the server, so it would not be available for return.  Because of that I believe it will only return soft deleted object